# AdminLTE multiple auth in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, adminlte

I'm trying to implement multi auth guards with AdminLTE in Laravel (version 6.x) and I have trouble to pass the guard (as $url variable) in login/register forms.
My API works fine without AdminLTE, and it works fine with normal user with AdminLTE.
I can display Admin login/register forms by taping "/login/admin" and "register/admin" in the address bar, but when I click login/register button I get "404 Not Found" page and in the address bar it displays "/login/$url"

I have changed the `login.blade.php` and `register.blade.php` in the following directory:

```
vendor/.../view/login.blade.php and vendor/.../view/register.blade.php
```

`LoginController.php:`

```php
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }

    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

`RegisterController.php:`

```php
protected function createAdmin(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $this->validateAdmin($data)->validate();

    $admin = Admin::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect()->intended('login/admin');
}
```

`routes/web.php:`

```php
Route::post('/login/admin', 'Auth\LoginController@adminLogin');
Route::post('/register/admin', 'Auth\RegisterController@createAdmin');
```

`login.blade.php:`

```
@isset($url)
  <form action="{{ url('login/$url') }}" method="post">
@else 
  <form action="{{ url(config('adminlte.login_url')) }}" method="post">
@endisset
```

`register.blade.php:`

```
@isset($url)
  <form action="{{ url('register/$url') }}" method="post">
@else 
  <form action="{{ url(config('adminlte.register_url')) }}" method="post">
@endisset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hard coding the `$url` as string as oppose to using it as a variable

This is due to using single quotes in the blade view files in the `url()` helper function argument

Just change it to double quotes

`login.blade.php:`

```
@isset($url)
  <form action="{{ url("login/$url") }}" method="post">
@else
  <form action="{{ url(config('adminlte.login_url')) }}" method="post">
@endisset
```

`register.blade.php:`

```
@isset($url)
  <form action="{{ url("register/$url") }}" method="post">
@else 
  <form action="{{ url(config('adminlte.register_url')) }}" method="post">
@endisset
```

> Changing files in vendor folder is redundant because your changes will be overridden on composer update/install

From [the docs](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#33---updating-from-package-1x-laravel-5x-to-package-version-2x-laravel-6x)

5. If you have published and modified the default master, page views or login views, you will need to update them too.

Option 1:

- Make a copy of the views you modified.
- Publish the views again, using

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\AdminLteServiceProvider" --tag=views
```

- Redo the modifications you did.

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you know where to make these changes other than in vendor? Because in the views files we have just one line ( @extends( 'adminlte::login'  ) or @extends( 'adminlte::register' ) ).

Comment: If these views are provided by a package, you can publish them using artisan to your resources views directory

Comment: Thanks too much again for you help. It saves me a lot of time.